# Should the FAQ specifically mention being industry neutral, when possible?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should our FAQ contain?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-should-our-faq-contain)

Realizing that many of the early members are related to software or IT, I've seen questions [like this one come up](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/199/possible-career-transitions-for-a-seasoned-software-developer) that ask for specific advice regarding career paths, that are industry-specific. I feel that these are off-topic, especially in this case because the question I reference already has an SE site dedicated to [matters of programmer professional life](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

So, should the FAQ advise OP's to keep their questions industry neutral when possible? I have no issue with users asking questions regarding issues that are only exist within a given industry, but generic questions like, "What are my career path options given that I am [insert job title]," I would argue, are off-topic and/or too localized, because they don't have to do with the workplace, but a specific person and career path.

Comment: Add your suggestion here (http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-should-our-faq-contain), and people can vote and comment there. Let's try not to split up that thread, unless there is a serious concern that requires extended vetting and discussion.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks.