# Delete reason for duplicate answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

Our [Help Center for Answering](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) explains that some answers are deleted because they are (emphasis mine):

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - **exact duplicates of other answers**
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

However, when voting to delete low quality answers, there is no option for "duplicate answer". (If anyone has the exact list of options and wants to add it in here, I would greatly appreciate it.) I usually end up selecting "No comment needed" and manually adding the following comment:

> This answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers. Please remember to [not repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others).

Can we add an option for duplicate answers as well, since that is explicitly one of our deletion reasons in the help center?

Comment: I'm not sure duplicate answers are supposed to be handled via the LQP queue, even. I think it's more appropiate to custom flag those. (At least thats what I do here and on SO and I haven't eaten a declined flag over it yet)

Comment: Adding a link to the duplicate answer is important here; we sometimes get "duplicate answer" flags with no further information, and we're probably not going to dig through 12 other answers to figure out what the flagger meant.  Linking to it in a comment informs everyone -- the author, who might fix or delete his answer himself, and the community, who can vote.