# Please curate the answers to the older-technologies question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How to attract people to work on very old and outdated technologies?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115206/how-to-attract-people-to-work-on-very-old-and-outdated-technologies) currently has 31 (non-deleted) answers.  Many of them appear to overlap a lot.  Several of them are very short.

We have a policy of [Back it up and don't repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/325).  Your task, should you choose to accept it, is to dig through all these answers with this policy in mind.  Are there late answers that don't add anything new?  Are there unsupported personal opinions in the answer slot?  Is there a problem with the *question* itself?

Comment: ...this Meta post will self-destruct in 5 seconds... [throws the laptop out of the window]

Comment: quick question, I am currently leaving a comment explaining the back it up, VTD those that have negative score and are not valuable, and flagging the ones not deletable yet as not an answer... is that ok? Should I skip the flagging or change them for mod flags instead?

Comment: NAA flags are good where applicable - sends posts to the review queue.

Comment: Already took a round and flagged/commented/signaled the user on several answers... will do more when I get time.

Comment: Well, I did say the question is too broad...

Comment: I deleted 3 of those 31 answers, which were entirely repeating the older answers, as well as another answer which got added later. I have left comments on a few answers asking to explain how the answer differs from the previous answers. The question is also closed (as of now), so hopefully there won't be any additional pileup.

Comment: The highest voted answers provide the worst advice.  Old COBOL programmer here, not going to retire "in ten years" as suggested by one answer.  Not going to bother with it.

Comment: @MaskedMan it seems that it already got 3 reopen votes... brace yourselves